# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 2 at Object.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch data from php mysql and display in console in JSON format. I am able to fetch data but when i try to display in JOSN format its giving me above error.

```
enter code here
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-sign-up',
templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent  {
constructor( private http: Http){
http.get('http://localhost/api/script.php')
.subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response.json());
}); 

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, please include your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try JSON.parse(response);

Comment: I think you have to show us this JSON. It sounds like the response from the call is not JSON at all.

Comment: thanks Narm. I got my results in JSON format. I converted data into JSON in php file. using print json_encode($rows); Is it right way to do? I am not sure